# Cover with unit test composite method c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

What is the best way of testing method

```
public void HandleRequests()
{
    var requests = _requestService.GetAll();
    foreach(var request in requests)
    {
        if (request.IsDelete)
        {
            _dateCheckerService.CheckRequest(request);
            _notificationService.Send(request);
            _invoiceService.CreateInvoice(request);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best way of testing if block. I guess that it's not good idea to verify that all 3 mthods were called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test this method (and specifically the if block) assuming you are injecting your dependencies (e.g. _requestService) and that those dependencies are abstractions that can be substituted by mocks then to test this method you need to assert that your various dependency methods received the expected request object e.g. _dateCheckerService.CheckRequest(request).

To accomplish this you can write your own mocks or use a mocking library such as [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) or [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/getting-started/).

The problem with testing this method is that you will have to do a lot of setup (creating four mocks, building your request collection...) and the end result will end up being very brittle. For example, imagine you decide to refactor and no longer require one of your dependencies, the outcome will be the same but your tests will break because you are testing not only what the method does, but how it is doing it, your test would depend on your implementation.

Unit testing your code is an excellent plan but in this case I would consider  whether the complexity and brittleness of the tests you would create is worth the benefit that the unit tests would bring, but only you can answer that.

If you do continue with testing I would recommend having more than one test for the if block, one for each dependency and each test should only have a single assert.

To test the If block;

1. Create two requests, one that is IsDelete = true, the other that is IsDelete = false. Setup your test such that _requestService.GetAll() will return return both of these requests.
2. Assert that _dateCheckerService.CheckRequest() is passed the IsDelete request but not the IsDelete = false request.
3. Repeat step two for _notificationService.Send() and _invoiceService.CreateInvoice();

Every dependency you test should be tested in its own test.

Comment: I need to create a three tests to check correctly if statement, right?

Comment: @xczxc to test this fully you need to assert that _datCheckerService.CheckRequest(), _notificationService.Send(), and _invoiceService.CreateInvoice() were all passed a request object and that the request object IsDelete. You could also test that they DO NOT receive requests that are not IsDelete. You can do this either as one giant test, or several smaller tests (which I recommend)

Comment: okay, but if i test it into smaller part, in this case for example i try to check _datCheckerService.CheckRequest() but in this case all other services will be called, is it okay for it? I just should concentrate on checking datechacker.CheckRequest and skip other results?

Comment: @xczxc yes thats fine. If your test checks everything then when it fails it is harder for you to determine why it failed. If however you have three tests but check only one dependency in each then when one of those tests fails you know why straight away. The fact that all three get called in each test doesn't affect the outcome of the test

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're injecting the services correctly with mocking data, a valid test (in my opinion) is to check the date, notification, and invoice services if they have done their jobs on the delete request.

However, I'd like to point out that the method you're testing is doing 2 things:

1. Get requests
2. Process requests

So it's name would be `GetAndHandleRequests`, which I believe isn't a good thing, you might want to change method signature to take the requests as an argument and handle them.

Comment: You mean that it's okay just to verify that all three methods were called while execution?

Comment: That's how I would test it.